# space complexity of simple factorial function in python

Tags: python, factorial, space-complexity

What should be the space complexity of this factorial function in python?

```
def fact(n):
    product = 1

    for i in range(2, n+1):
        product = product * i

    return product
```

This same idea in other languages like C will result in O(1) space complexity but for this example would range(2,n+1) result in a space complexity of O(n) space complexity?

Comment: use xrange instead of range

Comment: use `xrange` or `range` respectively if you are using `python2` or `python3`.

Comment: for n> 20, n! doesn't fit in a 64-bit integer. So the space complexity of your variable "product" is not constant at all and won't be far away of O(n).

Answer (score 1):

In py2.x `range` returns a list, so your for-loop is actually iterating over that list. Hence it is `O(N)` in terms of memory.

You can use `xrange` here which returns one item at a time.

Help on `xrange`:

```
xrange(start, stop[, step]) -> xrange object

Like range(), but instead of returning a list, returns an object that
generates the numbers in the range on demand.  For looping, this is 
slightly faster than range() and more memory efficient.
```

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on which python you are using.

In python 3, range is a generator, like the old xrange in python 2.

So it will be O(n) if you are using python 2.